# Equivalent to location.href.match in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner with Angular, and I'm trying to make menu marked as selected when I'm at his route, I'm currently trying to do this with $location, **here goes my plunkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/XsZDkKfzfJCGO1MPRWx5?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', ["directives.sidebar"])

angular.module("directives.sidebar", []).directive("sidebar", ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("click", function() {
        var sidebar = $(".nav-sidebar")
        sidebar.toggleClass("is-open");
      });

      var currentUrl = $location.path()
      switch(currentUrl) {
        case "/equipments":
          var navEquipments = $('li.nav-item')[0]
          $(navEquipments).addClass('nav-item--selected')
          break;
        case "/softwares":
          var navSoftwares = $('li.nav-item')[1]
          $(navSoftwares).addClass('nav-item--selected')
          break;
        case "/transducers":
          var navTransducers = $('li.nav-item')[2]
          $(navTransducers).addClass('nav-item--selected')
          break;
        case "/exams":
          var navExams = $('li.nav-item')[3]
          $(navExams).addClass('nav-item--selected')
          break;
      }

    }
  };
}])
```

you guys can give me some tips of how to do this?

Comment: location.href.match is plain javascript and has nothing to do with a framework. Please try to learn javascript first instead of a framework. Framework != language.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+string.match

Comment: @Erwinus I tried to do this with plain JS, but this is not working, I dont't understand why so I'm trying to do with angular $location service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve Your Problems.
Use Like:

```
switch(currentUrl) {
    case "/equipments":
      var navEquipments = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item')[0]);
      navEquipments.addClass('nav-item--selected')
      break;
    case "/softwares":
      var navSoftwares = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item')[1]);
      navSoftwares.addClass('nav-item--selected')
      break;
    case "/transducers":
      var navTransducers = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item')[2]);
      navTransducers.addClass('nav-item--selected')
      break;
    case "/exams":
      var navExams = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item')[3]);
      navExams.addClass('nav-item--selected')
      break;
  }
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EAOwRFrTWPEJNgRFr6g1?p=preview)

Comment: when I'm at /equipments/52 for example, this doesn't works, so I need something that match the "equipments" in url

Comment: I think then you cut substring of currentUrl.
like:

    `var currentUrl = $location.path().substring(0, $location.path().indexOf("/"));`